# BASH: check for errors before testing conditions

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a simple Bash script to monitor MySQL replication status. The script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbhost=192.168.1.2
repluser=root
replpasswd=password
echo "show slave status\G"|\
mysql -h $dbhost -u $repluser -p$replpasswd > tmpd 2>/dev/null
repl_IO=$(cat tmpd | grep "Slave_IO_Running" | cut -f2 -d':')
repl_SQL=$(cat tmpd | grep "Slave_SQL_Running" | cut -f2 -d':')
if [ $repl_IO != "Yes" -o $repl_SQL != "Yes" ] ; then
     echo
     echo -e "\033[31m Replication Error."
     echo -e "\033[0m"
     mail -s "replication error" email@domain.com < tmpd

else
     echo
     echo -e "\033[32mReplication is working fine"
     echo -e "\033[0m"

fi
```

The problem is that the script only works if both the master and the slave are up. If the master is down, and I run the script, it displays the error message and sends the email.
If both master/slave are up, the script displays "Replication is working fine" which is okay. But when I shutdown the slave and run the script, I get this error:

```
./monitor.bash: line 9: [: too many arguments

Replication is working fine
```

I know the problem is that since I'm querying the slave MySQL server, it's not finding it. So it's not checking the conditions Slave_IO_Running and Slave_SQL_Running. How would I go
about checking if the slave server is up BEFORE running those conditions. So in short, I only want "Replication is working fine" to be displayed, if both the master & slave are up and
running and it matches those conditions. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$repl_IO` and `$repl_SQL` are blank, then this:

```
if [ $repl_IO != "Yes" -o $repl_SQL != "Yes" ] ; then
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if [ != Yes -o != Yes ] ; then
```

and I think you can see why that doesn't work. You need either to wrap your parameter-expansions in double-quotes, so that they're treated as single arguments no matter what they contain:

```
if [ "$repl_IO" != "Yes" -o "$repl_SQL" != "Yes" ] ; then
```

or to use `[[...]]` instead of `[...]`, since it's a bit smarter with these things:

```
if [[ $repl_IO != "Yes" -o $repl_SQL != "Yes" ]] ; then
```

or both:

```
if [[ "$repl_IO" != "Yes" -o "$repl_SQL" != "Yes" ]] ; then
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your script: experienced shell programmers know that if a variable is empty the statement

if [ $foo = something ]

will look to the shell like

if [ = something ]

You can fix this with

if [ "$foo" = something ]

So in general, put " marks around all variables used inside [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Or use `[[ ]]` if you use bash, quoting variables isn't needed and it's more powerful than  `[ ]`.

greybot on the IRC channel of freenode said :

> [[ is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the [
>   command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless
>   you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend [[.

Comment: IMO you should just link the articles, and not include the bot's factoids.